# Prevent WebSphere from prepending "Error 40X:" to response when using response.sendError()

Tags: java, servlets, websphere, websphere-7

In our HTTP request handling code for some RESTful Web Services we are defining, we send error information in the response body, in addition to setting a status code.  For example:

```
response.sendError(403, "The error was X.");
```

When using Apache Tomcat as our application container, the response body only contains:

```
The error was X.
```

However, when using IBM WebSphere 7,  the response body is the following:

```
Error 403: The error was X.
```

Is there a way to prevent WebSphere from prepending the HTTP status to the response body?  If not, how could one send a JSON response?

Comment: Can you share the JS code used to get the error code and error description?

Answer (score 0):

Specify a customer error page for the error code and format as required

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>403</error-code>
   <location>/403.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: The idea is to not have to define any pages at all.  The response body is something that should be consumed as part of a RESTful service.